# Random characters being added to code

Tags: php, zend-framework

For some reason, an (PHP) application I uploaded to my webserver gets some random characters being added to the code, as you can see in the following screenshot (the 'o' is being added):

[View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhzfr.png)

Locally it's working fine. When I remove that character and refresh the page, it's there again! I get this in random files and on random moments...

Comment: check your code for malware at virustotal. It looks like it might have webshell

Comment: Which application ur using for uploading file to server? Filezilla?

Comment: No virus accoring to virustotal. Files are being uploaded through DeployHQ.com but also tried Filezilla and WinSCP. It happens after uploading.

Comment: What "o" is beeing added?

Comment: On line 77...
But it's not always an 'o', sometimes it's an 'h' or an 'n'

Comment: Rob-weDevise, did you find solution? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not.. Someone told me it may be an ascci-problem, but I don't think it is..